# Unity Button text not showing on some devices

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine, text

So earlier I was using best fit in all my text and it was working fine. But the ui became inconsistent with that and so I removed best fit and carefully set size for each screen/panel.

The problem now is that the text is not visible on some devices(like nexus 7).

But while on unity scene it works fine. Can anybody suggest how to proceed with this.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: set your unity editor game view to the same resolution as the nexus 7 and see if it is visible. you should share some code and screenshots, otherwise it is really hard to guess, what could be wrong, but still my guess is that the height of the UI.Text is too small, to test that you can set both "Horizontal Overflow"and "Vertical Overflow" to "Overflow".

Comment: Thanks JeanLuc... will try the overflow thing

Comment: YES! overflow settings always helps in debugging

Comment: try changing font.

Comment: For now the overflow thing is working but I have to use it selectively as some text components were exceeding their button boundary.

Comment: cool. I summed up several options as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

You have several options to adjust [UI.Text](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Text.html):

1. **increase RectTransform Width and Height**
2. **decrease the font size manually**
3. **adjust the font size by using [best fit](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Text-resizeTextForBestFit.html)**
4. **shorten your text**, which can be hard in rather lengthy languages
5. **let it overflow** by setting "[Horizontal Overflow](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Text-horizontalOverflow.html)" and/or "[Vertical Overflow](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.Text-verticalOverflow.html)" to "Overflow"

Then you need to test it in all resolutions (test extrem cases in aspect ratio and resolution) and in all languages your app supports.

You need to decide on each case, which options fits better.

Answer (score 0):

I had that problem, that I wasn't able to see any text from the Text Mesh Pro.
The reason why was that I hadn't installed the TMP packages or sth

To do that, you need to go to:
Window -> TextMeshPro -> Import TMP Essential Resources

And mabye go to:
Window -> TextMeshPro -> Import TMP Examples and Extras